# How do I edit the Menu on a VB6 form from the IDE?

Tags: vb6

I have a small application which contains a form with a menu along the top. I wish to make changes to the menu, but can't seem to do so from within the VB IDE. Every time I click on it to select it, the code for the item clicked is displayed.

Does anyone know how to edit the menu bar from within the IDE?

(I could edit the .frm file to make the necessary changes but I am reluctant to do this if a "proper" way exists.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can edit a VB6 menu in the IDE by bringing up the Menu Editor by selecting Tools > Menu Editor or by pressing Ctrl+E.

You can find fairly complete instructions [here](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson15.html) and [here](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_VB6_24hours&seqNum=176).

Comment: +1. The manual also offers complete instructions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262293(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Right click the form and select the **Menu Editor** option.

Answer (score 6):

Tools -> Menu Editor from the IDE menu bar.

The option should also be available on the Standard toolbar and the form context menu.

This modal dialog is only available when the form designer has focus.